# How to pass a string into a system call in xv6

Tags: c, xv6

I have to pass a string into a system call in xv6, so I know I have to use argstr(), my question lies with implementing it.

Here is what I have added to sysproc.c:

```
int sys_hello(char **str)
{
        int n = 15;
        argstr(n,  **str);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                cprintf("%c  testplzprint",str[i]);
        }
        cprintf("Hello World\n");

        return 0;
}
```

I am calling it from testcase.c:

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"

int main(void)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                hello("itworks");
        }
        exit();
}
```

I first implemented it without the testcase and argstr() and just printed hello and it worked well. I'm guessing my problem lies in how I am using argstr(). I really appreciate any help!

Update: sorry for not providing output, here it is right now.

```
js9313rr@smaug:/tmp/.x2go-js9313rr/media/disk/_cygdrive_C_Users_real0_Desktop_school_SPRING1_352/CSIS352/OS/OS lab 4/xv6-public-master$ make
gcc -fno-pic -static -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -MD -ggdb -m32 -Werror -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie   -c -o sysproc.o sysproc.c
sysproc.c: In function \u2018sys_hello\u2019:
sysproc.c:97:13: error: passing argument 2 of \u2018argstr\u2019 makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
  argstr(n,  **str);
             ^
In file included from sysproc.c:3:0:
defs.h:154:17: note: expected \u2018char **\u2019 but argument is of type \u2018char\u2019
 int             argstr(int, char**);
                 ^~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
<builtin>: recipe for target 'sysproc.o' failed
make: *** [sysproc.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. Fix them.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal program that will compile and not sections of code so that the community can analyze your program and provide suggestions.

Comment: Please describe, in excruciating detail, exactly what happened _instead of_ the argstr version working as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

1. make the `hello` prototype clear:

Do you want a array of strings ou just a string?

2. Your `sys_hello` prototype is wrong, it should be `sys_hello(void)`.

---

Here an example with an hello syscall taking one string as parameter:

```
int sys_hello(void)
  char *string;

  if(argstr(0, &string) < 0){
    return -1;
  }
  
  cprintf(string);
  
  return 0;
```